# Синтаксис файла .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, синтаксис

Допустим я в файле .htaccess задал какое либо условие RewriteCond и далее прописал 2 правила RewriteRule.

Будет ли RewriteCond применяться к обоим правилам или только к первому? Можно ли это как то настроить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказано в [документации](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) шаблон `RewriteRule` и непосредственно предшествующие ему `RewriteCond` определяют условия выполнения самого `RewriteRule`.

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met.

Более того, первым выполняется проверка шаблона, а затем уже `RewriteCond`. Это позволяет использовать подстановки из регулярного выражения в предшествующих  директивах `RewriteCond`, например так:

```
    RewriteCond "$1.php" -f
    RewriteCond "$1.html" !-f
    RewriteRule "^(.*).html$" "$1.php"
```

где символ подстановки `$1` соответствует группе шаблона `(.*)`.

Следовательно, невозможно напрямую связать несколько правил с одной группой условий. Однако существует возможность связать логику последующих проверок с результатом выполнения текущего правила с помощью [флагов](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html). Они располагаются в конце директивы (в квадратных скобках) и обычно записываются в сокращенном виде, но у них есть и полные, более понятные названия. Вот лишь некоторые из них:

- chain | C - цепочка. Если текущее правило не проходит проверку, то следующее правило тоже пропускается.
- skip | S=num - пропуск. При успешной проверке текущего правила пропускаются несколько следующих.
- last | L - При успешном выполнении текущего правила процесс перезаписи завершается.